# Wait until data fetched

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fetch, next.js13, react-query

Nextjs 13

I have a custom hook to load userData.

```
const useUser = () => {
return useQuery({
    queryKey: ['authentificated_user'],
    queryFn: () => getMe(),
    refetchOnMount: false,
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
    refetchOnReconnect: false,
    retry: 0,
})
```

}

And Profile menu that change on auth buttons if no authorized user

```
const Profile = () => {
const userQuery = useUser()

if (userQuery.isLoading) {
    return (
        <SkeletonLoader>
            <SkeletonCircle size={28} />
        </SkeletonLoader>
    )
}

if (!userQuery.data) {
    return (
        <div className="flex gap-2">
            <Button size="sm">Sign in</Button>
            <Button size="sm" variant="outline">Sign up</Button>
        </div>
    )
}

return (
    <div className="relative inline-flex">
        <Menu>
            <Menu.Button>
                <Avatar url={userQuery.data.image ?? undefined} alt="Profile avatar." size="xs" />
            </Menu.Button>
            <Transition
                as={Fragment}
                enter="transition ease-out duration-100"
                enterFrom="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                enterTo="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                leave="transition ease-in duration-75"
                leaveFrom="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                leaveTo="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
            >
                <Menu.Items className="absolute right-0 mt-2 border shadow rounded-md w-56 divide-y-1 py-1">
                    <div className="px-1">
                        <Menu.Item>
                            <Button variant="ghost" size="sm" className="justify-start">Profile</Button>
                        </Menu.Item>
                    </div>
                    <div className="px-1">
                        <Menu.Item>
                            <Button variant="ghost" size="sm" className="justify-start text-red-500">Logout</Button>
                        </Menu.Item>
                    </div>
                </Menu.Items>
            </Transition>
        </Menu>
    </div>
)
```

}

**I need to fetch user or null state if no user before navbar loads. I mean to get past this part:** Cuz now it's takes like 3 second to load and all that time user see only skeleton loader. Looks wierd

```
if (userQuery.isLoading) {
return (
    <SkeletonLoader>
        <SkeletonCircle size={28} />
    </SkeletonLoader>
)
```

}

All Header Code:

```
const Header = () => {
const [navOpen, setNavOpen] = useState(false)

return (
    <nav className="fixed w-full shadow-sm z-30 bg-white">
        <div className='mx-auto max-w-6xl'>
            <div className='flex items-center justify-between h-11 md:px-4 px-2'>
                <div className='h-full flex items-center gap-8'>
                    <div className="flex h-full items-center gap-2">
                        <Button className="flex md:hidden" variant="ghost" startIcon={<LuMenu size={26} />} size="icon" onClick={() => setNavOpen(true)} />
                        <div className='inline-flex items-center justify-center bg-black text-white h-full px-2.5'>
                            <LuCommand size={26} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className='hidden md:inline-flex'>
                        <MobileNav navOpen={navOpen} setNavOpen={setNavOpen} />
                        <NavItems />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="flex items-center gap-4">
                    <Button startIcon={<BiSearch size={24} />} variant="ghost" size="icon" className="rounded-full" />
                    <Profile />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
)
```

}

Comment: Try making a Codesandbox or similar, so we can help you. I don't understand what you need here, do you want to display other parts of the UI before the user's hook gets data?